# Get all Magento URLs by store view

Tags: magento-1.9, url, sitemaps

I'm looking to retrieve all URLs of a Magento website (CMS pages, categories, products...) subdivided by store view.
Something like the default Magento Sitemap, but with a different format: specifically I'm trying to get a "one URL per row" plain text file, one for each store view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sander-mangel I've developed a solution for my specific case: https://gist.github.com/RiccardoB/2117046a97719b413c8a

If you have any optimization/fix to suggest, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at how Magento generates it's `sitemap.xml` file.

Specifically the `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap` class method `generateXml`.
For example, following snippet generates them for the categories, I've rewritten it a little to export to a flat text file.

```
$ioWrite = new Varien_Io_File();
$path = ''; 
$ioWrite->open(array('path' => $path));
$ioWrite->streamOpen($path.'urls.txt');

$storeId =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$date    = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');
$baseUrl = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);

/**
 * Generate categories sitemap
 */
$changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/category/changefreq', $storeId);
$priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/category/priority', $storeId);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_category')->getCollection($storeId);
$categories = new Varien_Object();
$categories->setItems($collection);
Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_categories_generating_before', array(
    'collection' => $categories
));
foreach ($categories->getItems() as $item) {
    $ioWrite->streamWrite(htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl()));
}
unset($collection);
$ioWrite->close();
```

Add the code from the class to your own script to generate a text file

Comment: Thanks @Sander for the hints, I've got a solution starting from this.